# Adding margin in search function

Tags: jquery, html, css

My problem is that when using search function, pictures get stuck together because every 4th picture has no margin - all because they have to fit into certain div with, so end of the rows can't be any margin or padding. But when search gives for example 4th and 5th picture, they are together, because 4th, 8th and 12th picture don't have margin. Every other picture have right margin 60px.

I managed to get margin to 0 like that:

```
     li:nth-child(4) {
         margin-right: 0px;
      }

     li:nth-child(8) {
         margin-right: 0px;
      }
     li:nth-child(12) {
         margin-right: 0px;
      }
```

Definitely not the best way, but then it was only idea I had how to manage it.

HTML:

```
 <header class="main-header">

   <form id="live-search" class="styled" method="post">
     <fieldset>
        <input type="text" class="text-input input"      placeholder="Search.." id="filter" value="" />
     </fieldset>
  </form>
</header>
<div class="container">
        <ul class="list" id="imageGallery">
            <li>
                <a href="photos/01.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="Title">
                <img src="photos/thumbnails/01.jpg" alt="Text">
                </a>
                <p>Title text</p>
            </li>
           ........
      </ul>
    </div>
```

And search function is like that:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#filter").keyup(function(){

    // Retrieve the input field text
    var filter = $(this).val();

    // Loop through the  list
    $(".list li").each(function(){

        // If the list item does not contain the text phrase fade it out
        if ($(this).text().search(new RegExp(filter, "i")) < 0) {
            $(this).fadeOut();

        // Show the list item if the phrase matches
        } else {
            $(this).show();
        }
     });

   }); 
});
```

Is there any fast way to add margin to pictures that are end of the row when they are searched?

EDIT:

Added Github link to project:
[Github](https://github.com/AskoK/Gallery-3)

Comment: where's html code? nd if possible give the jsfiddle link

Comment: Maybe would be enough `li:nth-child(4n)` but without seeing MCVE, it is quite unclear what you are asking...  And it sounds like you'd have better to do than using any kind of workaround, but still, it is hard to figure it out without seeing any concrete sample of what you are talking about...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `:nth-child` more effectively.

If you know you have 4 items per row..... `:nth-child(4n)` will target every 4th item (4, 8, 12, 16, etc.)

```css
.container {
  margin: 20px auto;
  max-width: 400px;
  font-size: 0.7em;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0; }

li {
  margin-bottom: .25em;
  padding: .25em;
  background: #eee;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

li:nth-child(4n) {
  background: #aae;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li>List Item 1</li>
    <li>List Item 2</li>
    <li>List Item 3</li>
    <li>List Item 4</li>
    <li>List Item 5</li>
    <li>List Item 6</li>
    <li>List Item 7</li>
    <li>List Item 8</li>
    <li>List Item 9</li>
    <li>List Item 10</li>
    <li>List Item 11</li>
    <li>List Item 12</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```